# Can i add two axis in a spiderweb highcharts and click x-axis label navigate to another page?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, coldfusion

Currently I am using spiderweb highcharts with ColdFusion. Can i set two axis in the spiderweb? Besides that, how can i link to another page when i click on the x-axis'label with data passing?

Below is my code. TQ

```
<cfscript>
    categories= ['Overall','Appt Booking', 'Reception', 'Service Advisor', 'Completion Delivery Process'] ;

    series = [{
            'name': 'Last Month',
            'data': [3.775,3.5, 3.9, 4, 3.7],
            'pointPlacement': 'on'
        }, {
            'name': 'MTD',
            'data': [ 3.775, 3.7, 3.5, 3.9, 4],
            'pointPlacement': 'on'
        }, {
            'name': 'Target',
            'data': [3.725, 3.8,3.5, 3.7, 3.9],
            'pointPlacement': 'on'
        }];
</cfscript>
<html>
    <head> 
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        polar: true,
                        type: 'line'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Budget vs spending',
                        x: -1000
                    },
                    pane: {
                        size: '70%'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: <cfoutput>#serializeJson(categories)#</cfoutput>,
                        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                        lineWidth: 0
                    },
                    yAxis: [{
                        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        min: 3,
                        endOnTick: true,
                        showLastLabel: true,
                        tickPositions: [3,3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
                    }],
                    tooltip: {
                        shared: true,
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 70,
                        layout: 'vertical'
                    },
                    series: <cfoutput>#serializeJson(series)#</cfoutput>
                });
            });
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about limitation in ColdFusion, but in Highcharts you can simply use `xAxis.labels.formatter` to use `<a>` tags in labels, see demo in [the docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter).

For multiple yAxes - it's the same, Highcharts supports multiple yAxes, simply use structure as `yAxis: [ { ... }, { ... } ]` and you will get two axes. Second yAxis will be empty, so don't forget to connect specific series to that axis using [`series.yAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.yAxis).

Comment: You welcome. Instead of writing comment "thanks", accept the answer. We don't want to violate rules of Stackoverflow, right? ;)